# Is there an easy way to access all transactions recorded in a bitcoin block with certain block height using Python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, get, bitcoin

I would like to retrive all transactions within a block with a certain block height, without running a full node or downloading a few GB of data.

Not sticking to Python, tried to use the `Block Height` section of [this](https://www.blockchain.com/api/blockchain_api). Following the example given there,

```
https://blockchain.info/block-height/$100?format=json
```

returns:

```
Invalid Numerical Value
```

Is there an easy, Pythonic way to do this?

Comment: always put full error message (starting at word "Traceback") in question (not comment) as text (not screenshot). There are other useful information.

Comment: did you try without char `$` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to use without `$` which was only information that `$block_height` is not part of url but variable which you have to replace,

```
https://blockchain.info/block-height/100?format=json
```

---

```
import requests

r = requests.get('https://blockchain.info/block-height/100?format=json')
data = r.json()

#print(r.text)
#print(data)
print(data['blocks'][0]['hash'])
```

Comment: Thanks! There are more issues with this API, a follow-up is asked here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61880129/why-does-blockchain-com-api-only-return-recipient-base58-addresses-and-omits-bec