# Why does BLOCKCHAIN.COM API only return recipient BASE58 addresses and omits BECH32s?

Tags: python, python-3.x, api, get, bitcoin

Following [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61859325/8565438), I am trying to access all transactions within the #630873 block in the bitcoin blockchain.

```
import requests

r = requests.get('https://blockchain.info/block-height/630873?format=json')
data = r.json()
```

When inspecting the (0-indexed) 4th transaction within this block (via `data['blocks'][0]['tx'][4]['out']`), I get this:

```
[{'n': 0,
  'script': '0014d0aba2c93bac0fcafafe43f2ad39d664ba51910d',
  'spent': False,
  'tx_index': 0,
  'type': 0,
  'value': 19571491},
 {'addr': '1A7tWftaGHohhGcJMVkkm4zAYnF53KjRnU',
  'n': 1,
  'script': '76a9146406a0a47d4ed716f6ddf2eeca20c725932763f188ac',
  'spending_outpoints': [{'n': 0, 'tx_index': 0}],
  'spent': True,
  'tx_index': 0,
  'type': 0,
  'value': 3928145371}]
```

Only the `addr` of the second recipient of this transaction is included. On the blockchain.com website this transaction looks like:

[image]

The `bc1q6z469jfm4s8u47h7g0e26wwkvja9rygdqpeykd` address is visible there. How to access it through the API?

The unaccessible address has `BECH32` format, while the accessible one has `BASE58` (which information I get by clicking on the address on the website). Those transactions which I was able to retrieve the reciepient address, had `BASE58` format.

[Link to the block I am talking about.](https://www.blockchain.com/btc/block/00000000000000000009eefb7971196febbea455b2bbc18ea65b57c64054fa03).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Blochchain.com API does not fully support bech32 addresses yet.

So you could use another provider such as Blockstream or Blockchair.

Or you can also derive the addresses from the P2WPKH script. For example using BitcoinLib (Disclaimer: my library):

```
from bitcoinlib.transactions import script_deserialize
from bitcoinlib.keys import Address

locking_script = '0014d0aba2c93bac0fcafafe43f2ad39d664ba51910d'
scr = script_deserialize(locking_script)
a = Address(hashed_data=scr['hashes'][0], script_type=scr['script_type'])
print(a.address)
```